# How to create tab spacing in the beginning of a text field (discordjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to use `\t` to create a tab spacing in an embed using my discordjs bot to no avail. I'm sure there's an easy solution I couldn't find googling so thanks in advance for any help.

Code:

```
.addFields(
                { name: 'Test' , value: '\tFirst Line\n\tSecond Line\n\tThird Line\n\tFourth Line' }
)
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, no tab or spacing at all before the value elements.

Comment: Not going to pretend to know how discordjs works but how is that rendered? Is it using HTML? If so - what element is it rendering into and does it have styling (CSS)? If so it could be that the styling takes over when it comes to render and therefore it strips tab away because it is clearly registering it otherwise you would see the `\t` in front of the items.

Comment: It's a string which uses markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it does not seem possible. All fields are trimmed, as it is stated in the Discord API documentation :

> Leading and trailing whitespace characters are not included (they are trimmed automatically).

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-limits-limits

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, unfortunate but oh well.